# .htaccess file treat subdirectory as root directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to allow access to certain resources such as JS, CSS, etc. while silently redirecting everything else to /index.php which will eventually decide whether the remainder of the content exists or not. This is to allow friendly URLs without everything (i.e. static files) going through PHP.

I am testing the code in the /public_html/test/ directory but some .htaccess directives need /test/ while other don't. When I have it working to my satisfaction I will move it to the /public_html/ directory but I don't want to have to edit the file to get it working in the new location. What I'm saying is that I want the file to work the same way regardless of the location and without having to hard-code the full path in (so I can move it to a server with a different structure).

I have the following .htaccess file in `http://localhost/test/`:

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Specifically deny /includes/*
RewriteRule ^includes/ - [R=404,L]

# Allow /images/*, /css/* & /js/* but deny everything else, e.g. /lib/*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test/images/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test/css/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test/js/
RewriteRule . - [R=404,L]
```

I'm going to change the last rule to rewrite to /index.php later instead of giving a 404. For the moment I just want to get the .htaccess file working a bit nicer.

How can I make the rules consistent (i.e. remove `test` from each `RewriteCond`)? I would like to be able to test it in the /test/ directory but then move it to the web root directory (i.e. inside /public_html/) or even one lower without changing the paths. I have tried changing `RewriteBase` but I don't understand exactly what it does and I haven't seen any difference with other values.

How can I make this .htaccess file work if I move it down to the same level as /public_html/?

Ideally I'd like the following structure:

```
public_html/
public_html/test/
public_html/test/css/
public_html/test/images/
public_html/test/includes/
public_html/test/js/
public_html/test/lib/
public_html/test/index.php
public_html/.htaccess
```

where everything still works if I move it to:

```
public_html/
public_html/css/
public_html/images/
public_html/includes/
public_html/js/
public_html/lib/
public_html/index.php
.htaccess
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a dynamic `RewriteBase` generation rule before your rule:

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On

## Determine the RewriteBase automatically/dynamically
RewriteCond $0#%{REQUEST_URI} ^([^#]*)#(.*)\1$
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [E=BASE:%2]

# Specifically deny /includes/*
RewriteRule ^includes/ - [R=404,L]

# Allow /images/*, /css/* & /js/* but deny everything else, e.g. /lib/*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^%{ENV:BASE}(images|css|js)/ [NC]
RewriteRule . - [R=404,L]
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain what it does? I know that `$0` matches `^.*$` but what does the rest do?

Comment: That trick is explained here: http://www.zeilenwechsel.de/it/articles/8/Using-mod_rewrite-in-.htaccess-files-without-knowing-the-RewriteBase.html

Comment: I've currently got `index.php` removal working, while redirecting internally to `index.php`, while allowing direct access to anything under `js/`, `css/` and `images/` but with a static `RewriteBase`. I'm thinking about how I modify my solution with this solution to get both things working at the same time. The good thing about this is that when I get it working I'll be able to run an application in any other directory simply by putting an `index.php` file in it (I think). Hmm, how do I know which directory has `index.php` in it...

Comment: The first rule I showed her is dynamically generating the current RewriteBsse path and storing it in `${ENV:BASE}` environment variable. This this variable can be then used in other rules as you can see from example above. This gives you flexibility to avoid using any static RewriteBase and use this htaccess in any sub directory.

Comment: Yeah, I saw the two ways in the link (the link didn't work first time I tried it). I saw something recently about rerunning a rule until it's false, so maybe I can use that to check for `/foo/bar/index.php`, `/foo/index.php`, `/index.php`, etc.

Comment: I think you're talking about some other thing. My answer was for this requirement `remove test from each RewriteCond`